# How can I find and click a button in Selenium using the 'type' and/or 'value' properties?

Tags: python, class, button, types

How to find button in selenium using type and/or value?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq9R2.png)

trying to click the button that is identified by the type and value.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.neopets.com/prehistoric/omelette.phtml")

button1 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*input[text()='Grab some Omelette']")
button1.click()
time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  You just need to use `@value` to indicate the value attribute.  You should also use the singular version of `find_element` since you are only targeting a single element.

For example:

```
...
driver.get("https://www.neopets.com/prehistoric/omelette.phtml")

button1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Grab some Omelette']")
button1.click()
time.sleep(10)
```

Alternatively you could do the same with the type attribute:

```
button1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='submit']")
```